# Saying that the mail has an attached form filled up by me?

Tags: expression-choice

Let's say I'm writing a letter to a university and my mail has an application form attached to it. How can I say it in a more formal and concise way than "Please see the attached application form that I filled up." or "Please find attached my filled-up application form."

I would appreciate it if the answer starts with "Please see..." or "Please find attached..." Thank you!

Comment: "... my completed application form." (As an aside: for forms, BrE uses *filled **in***; AmE uses *filled **out***. Baths are filled **up**.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! But, doesn't it sound like the application form is my possession and therefore not for them? This is why I'm hoping for a better rewording for "Please find attached my filled-up application form."

Comment: "Please find attached my completed application form." You have attached it; it is in their possession. Even "Please see my completed application form" **implies** it's attached, or how could they see it? [I think *find attached* is better: it tells them explicitly where it is.]

Comment: @bimboxX If the form isn't actually attached it is perfectly alright to say 'Please find enclosed (herewith) my completed application form.' 'Herewith' is not essential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of the following are acceptable:

> Please see my completed application form.
>
> Please find attached my completed application form.
>
> Please see the attached application.